# Stopwords removal (surprisingly) decreases accuracy of naive bayes model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, naive-bayes-classifier

I'm building a model that predicts the subreddit of a given reddit submission. I have a question regarding pre-processing my text (submissions). The order I followed when pre-processing my text was:

1. Remove punctuations
2. Remove stopwords
3. Lemmatize the remaining text

I then fed the text into a [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).
While this got me decent accuracy on my naive bayes model, I discovered I was getting much better results (about ~5% gains) when I skipped #2 altogether. What are some reasons why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that at least one of the stop words you have removed is predictive of the subreddit category.

This could be a post style thing - e.g. in a simple case the posts have different typical lengths depending on class, and counting high frequency words gives a good proxy for article length. You could test that by using article length as an additional feature whilst still removing the stop words, and see whether any of the 5% improvement is accounted for by that.

It is possible that certain stop words are really more associated with certain topics. Perhaps they occur in common phrases associated with the topic. You could check feature importance from the weights and see which of the stop words were being used most heavily by the model.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I looked up ways to find feature weights for a given class, but didn't find anything that was easy to deploy. I think I'll implement a  wordcloud and see if I can discern any patterns with the stopwords.

Comment: I don't know naive bayes, perhaps you can get that information via `get_params`, but you'd need to know how to interpret it.